# How can I change my population's political preferences?

Tags: victoria-2

How can I change the political leanings of my populace and/or upper house? For instance, is it possible to go from a 30% liberal upper house to 90% liberal (by changing the actual preferences of the pops as opposed to just gerrymandering classes through suffrage reform)?

What are the possible ways of converting political affiliation? How effective and how quick are they?

Answer (score 2):

The only real tool to influence your populations ideology you have is to spend a national focus on the party loyalty of your choice. This is fairly slow and as it costs a national focus slot very expensive.

Otherwise, you pretty much have to encourage people into the pops you want, i.e. capitalists are usually liberal, aristocrats are usually conservative or reactionary; etc; try to create a state, which conforms to the ideology you want.

Keep in mind though, that as long as you are a monarchy, you can simply decide what party constitutes your government. The game is designed to give you few tools to influence the ideology of the broad masses, but most countries can simply go against the wishes of the population.

Answer (score 0):

National focus doesn't work if the country holds no common elections.

The only real tool to shape your PEOPLE's ideology, in contrast to your upper house or your ruling party, is militancy and consciousness.

[image]

The POP detail screen shows the chance the given POP is leaning towards a certain ideology. From this screenshot, I bet you don't want your people have to militancy greater than 6, otherwise they turn to anarcho liberal.

As for controlling militancy and consciousness, it's another lesson.

Upper house composition is based on the upper house reform you have and your people's ideology composition.